# Read/Write through web service into iOS app?

Tags: ios, json, api, web-services

I've a simple native iOS app (Swift 4, Xcode 9) and I built the DB on SQL server.

I want the app to read/write student info (ID, Name, Age).

1. What should I use as web service to communicate between the app and the DB?
2. Is the web service secure enough to pass the data online?
3. How can I pass the text field data from the app to the web service in order to save it into the `SQL` server?

Comment: you must develop webservice to upload data on SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop an API which will be hosted on the server. Api will communicate directly with the DB for reading and writing date. Mobile app can communicate to API using REST or GraphQL. Then you need to develop methods on the app to handle the authentication. You can use oAuth or you can implement your own methods to handle user authentication. Regarding the network security you can use HTTPS connection with TLS certificate to  secure the communication between app and web service.

You can develop API in any programing language (PHP, NodeJS, Java, .Net ....) but since you are working with Swift you can checkout some swift server side frameworks like:

https://github.com/vapor/vapor

https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura

For convenience if you can checkout some the API platform if they can suit your needs. For example:

http://deployd.com/

http://parseplatform.org/